# Square of the Maxwell Field Tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, field-theory, tensor-calculus, conventions

I want to prove that the square of the Maxwell field tensor
$$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=2(B^2-E^2),$$
but I got $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=2(-B^2+E^2)$ instead.
Here's what I did:
$$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=F_{0\nu}F^{0\nu}+F_{i\nu}F^{i\nu}=F_{0i}F^{0i}+F_{i0}F^{i0}+F_{ij}F^{ij}=2F_{i0}F^{i0}+F_{ij}F^{ij}$$
First part:
$$F_{i0}=\partial_iA_0-\partial_0A_i=E_i=-E^i$$
$$F^{i0}=\partial^0A^i-\partial^iA^0=-E^i$$
$$F_{i0}F^{i0}=E^iE^i=E^2$$
Second part:
$$F_{ij}=\partial_iA_j-\partial_jA_i=-\epsilon_{ijk}B^k$$
$$F^{ij}=-\epsilon^{ijk}B_k$$
$$F_{ij}F^{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{ijl}B^kB_l=2\delta_k^lB^kB_l=2B^kB_k=-2B^kB^k=-2B^2$$

What's wrong with my derivation?

Answer (score 1):

$F_{i0}F^{i0}=E^iE^i=-E^2$ for both $g^{00}=\pm1$ . There is a minus sign error in the second term also.

Answer (score -1):

Dear What you did is perfect. The problem lies in where you are looking for your answer. Your reference is derived with different metric and you used metric $diag(1,-1)$. Nothing else is wrong.
Just a matter of metric choice.

Answer (score -1):

Your derivation is correct, but is incorrect how you evaluate the square of the electric and magnetic field. In a general metric the square of a vector (aka. its square length) is obtained by the following formula:

$$ 
E^2 = g_{\mu \nu} E^\mu E^\nu = E_\mu E^\mu .
$$

When you have evaluated, for example the electric field, you called $E^2 = E^i E^i$ instead of $E_i E^i$.